# How to call Vue.render (for Facebook login) from inside a function

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

Still trying to wrap my mind around how nativescript-vue works and how different it is from vue.js ... I'm trying to incorporate Facebook login in my nativescript app. The following code in app.js (from [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-facebook/tree/master/demo-vue)) works just fine:

```
import * as application from 'tns-core-modules/application';
import Login from "./components/FBLogin";

import {
    init,
    LoginBehavior
} from 'nativescript-facebook';

import FacebookPlugin from "nativescript-facebook/vue";
Vue.use(FacebookPlugin);

Vue.config.silent = false;

application.on(application.launchEvent, function (args) {
    init("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", LoginBehavior.LoginBehaviorWeb);
});

new Vue({
    render: h => h('frame', [h(Login)])
}).$start();
```

Now, I don't want to start off the app by going straight to the FB login ... I'm trying to call this Login from a function in a different component:

```
function FBLogin() {
    // some stuff
    // ...
    h => h('frame', [h(Login)])
}
```

Does not work (does nothing) neither creating a new Vue instance inside the function... how can I call the FB login from inside the function? Or I'll just have to call a new component with the FB login code?

Thanks!!

M

Comment: How you are calling `FBLogin()`? The Vue instance should receive the frame in the render function, looks like you are not returning the frame there.

Comment: Thanks - I ended up creating a new component and calling the component, it worked fine and the FB code is isolated there.